# How to set sandbox account for Paypal Pro Hosted Solution for Italy

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to setup a sandbox account for Paypal Pro Hosted for Italy on [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com).

I have tried with an US Paypal account, other country than Italy account, live account for Italy and nothing seem to work.

When I use `"Create Account"` button it won't save the seller or buyer account that has country Italy.

I believe I need the country to be as Italy. We use an eCommerce platform that allows us to specify the country when setting payment methods and having the country as Italy it matters.
In live mode all is working on the website. I need that sandbox account working for testing new stuff.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it worked to set the country to IT.
For the seller account you can set country to Italy now.

Answer (score 1):

I also attempted to create an Italian account in the sandbox and failed.

I was able to successfully create an Australian and a German account so it appears the issue is isolated to Italian account creation attempts.

The next step would be for you to file a ticket with PayPal Merchant Technical Support at https://www.paypal.com/mts. Click on "Contact Technical Support" to start the ticket.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I'll try to contact support. I'll post whatever I'll learn.